# How to Convert Excel Value from scientific notation to excel C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have a application to read a excel cell value which is in scientific notation.

I have tried the below code :

```
decimal dec = Decimal.Parse("1.01703E+11", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any);
```

Result : 101703000000M

But the excel value is different from the result
This is the correct excel value "101703000026"

Connection method

```
public DataSet ReadExcelData(string Path)
    {
        OleDbConnection oledbConn = null;
        try
        {
            // need to pass relative path after deploying on server
            string path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@Path);

            oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';");
            oledbConn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            // selecting distict list of Slno 
            cmd.Connection = oledbConn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [DailySalesReport$]";

            oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            oleda.Fill(ds);

            // binding form data with grid view
            return ds;

        }
        // need to catch possible exceptions
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            oledbConn.Close();
        }
    }
```

How can I get the correct value. Please advice.
 [This is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2th0w.jpg)

Comment: Please post your code. The format is used only to *display* cell values. The cell actually contains a proper number. Unless you actually forced the field to be a string with a `'`

Comment: Both the Jet Provider and the Open XML SDK will read the number just fine. Even if you use Interop, the *value* will be a normal number. What did you try? Why are you trying to parse a *text* value instead of reading the numerical value?

Comment: BTW the scientific string you posted doesn't end in 26. `1.01703E+11` *is*  `101703000000`, that's just math. `Decimal.Parse` worked correctly. Where did you find that string?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos question updated. Please check

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the answer i'm getting from the excel is not 101703000000

Comment: The string you posted has no 26 in it. You haven't posted how you *read* that value either. Your code just fills a datasheet, and yet you mention databinding to grids. Where is the data binding code? What it the *grid column's* format? Even if the DataTable column has a decimal type, you won't see all digits if the *grid* uses a scientific format

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : question updated please check